# AJAX Login/Register and Comment forms

Tags: forms, ajax, comments, users

I'm looking for a solution to handle the comments, login and register via AJAX. Why ? Actually I'm loading my content in Overlay-Boxes and get the content with JSON-Views, but it should be possible to comment the articles in these boxes.

The problem is that the box with the content is only loaded when you click a link. I just downloaded a module to realize the AJAX form, but this only worked in static content like mysite.org/nodes/15 - no problem. But when I load a node via AJAX in an overlay-Box it doesn't work, because I must restart the module to grab the new loaded form.

I hope you understood what my problem is. Is there any solution to realise my problem, or is there already a module that I can use for this?

Comment: Which module are you talking about?

Comment: ajax_comments and ajax_register. I dont know what to add to the content which i get via ajax to init the ajax_register and ajax_comments